# How to sniff packets between a iOS device and an ethernet (via USB) device

Tags: ios, network, usb, ethernet, proxy

I have a USB camera that does work with iOS devices only on a specific application made by the manufacturer. When connected, it creates an ethernet interface for which I'm always assigned the same IP address and then when launching the app the camera shows up.

There is no documentation for this device or known API to make it work on other devices or apps.

How can I monitor the traffic between the device and the USB camera in order to find out endpoints (wether HTTP/HTTPS or not) to be able to use the camera on other devices?

If a proxy is a good option, how can I set up a proxy in between the usb "network", my computer and my iOS device?

The option of the virtual network created by MacOS is (at first glance) not the good approach because my iOS device port is already in use by the USB camera.

What could be the solutions? (If I need to tweak the iOS device in a jailbreak-way option it's ok)

Comment: Have you set up proxy software in the past in general? https://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: @bmike Tried once, I can visualize setting up a proxy with a classical schema but in this case: since the usb camera creates the network and the iOS device is the only device connected to it (since its a usb cable) I wonder how I can involve my computer into the network and then set up the proxy

Comment: Charles will be less expensive than a professional USB-C analyzer. Those exist if you care to spend $4k US and really need to know what’s implemented.

Comment: If there is Ethernet involved you could try to place a network switch with mirroring port (most network switches support this mode, even the cheap) in between, connect a computer to the mirroring port and capture everything using Wireshark in promiscuous mode.